# RGB image to binary image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, rgb

I want to load an RGB image in MATLAB and turn it into a binary image, where I can choose how many pixels the binary image has. For instance, I'd load a 300x300 png/jpg image into MATLAB and I'll end up with a binary image (pixels can only be #000 or #FFF) that could be 10x10 pixels.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
load trees % from MATLAB
gray=rgb2gray(map); % 'map' is loaded from 'trees'. Convert to grayscale.
threshold=128;
lbw=double(gray>threshold);
BW=im2bw(X,lbw); % 'X' is loaded from 'trees'.
imshow(X,map), figure, imshow(BW)
```

(I got some of the above from an internet search.)

I just end up with a black image when doing the `imshow(BW)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your first problem is that you are confusing [indexed images](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/image-types.html#f2-155) (which have a colormap `map`) and [RGB images](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/image-types.html#f2-12468) (which don't). The sample built-in image `trees.mat` that you load in your example is an indexed image, and you should therefore use the function [`ind2gray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/ind2gray.html) to first convert it to a [grayscale intensity image](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/image-types.html#f2-175). For RGB images the function [`rgb2gray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2gray.html) would do the same.

Next, you need to determine a threshold to use to convert the grayscale image to a binary image. I suggest the function [`graythresh`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/graythresh.html), which will compute a threshold to plug into [`im2bw`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2bw.html) (or the newer [`imbinarize`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imbinarize.html)). Here is how I would accomplish what you are doing in your example:

```
load trees;             % Load the image data
I = ind2gray(X, map);   % Convert indexed to grayscale
level = graythresh(I);  % Compute an appropriate threshold
BW = im2bw(I, level);   % Convert grayscale to binary
```

And here is what the original image and result `BW` look like:

[image]

[image]

For an RGB image input, just replace `ind2gray` with `rgb2gray` in the above code.

With regard to resizing your image, that can be done easily with the Image Processing Toolbox function [`imresize`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imresize.html), like so:

```
smallBW = imresize(BW, [10 10]);  % Resize the image to 10-by-10 pixels
```

Comment: Thanks, what about my other question: where can I choose to set the output image to be like 10x10 pixels?

Answer (score 0):

It is because `gray` is in the scale of `[0,1]`, whereas `threshold` is in `[0,256]`.
This causes `lbw` to be a big array of `false`. Here is a modified code that solves the problem:

```
load trees % from MATLAB
gray=rgb2gray(map); % 'map' is loaded from 'trees'. Convert to grayscale.
threshold=128/256;
lbw=double(gray>threshold);
BW=im2bw(X,lbw); % 'X' is loaded from 'trees'.
imshow(X,map), figure, imshow(BW)
```

And the result is:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, what about my other question: where can I choose to set the output image to be like 10x10 pixels?